# Xcode setting for app supports only iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Apple review team rejected my app due to some bugs. actually i set Xcode settings that app supports only for iPhone. But apple review team test app in iPad4 having iOS 8.1 version. actually in iPad4 video stream not working, it working properly in iPhone5 having iOS 8.1.1 version.

my requirement is app should supports only for iPhone.

my Xcode deployment info settings is
 Devices : iPhone

After submitting build binary device information:
Device Requirements

iOS Version:
5.1

Supported Architectures: 
armv7

Device Family: 
iPhone / iPod Touch

Comment: i think you uploaded screenshots of iPad in iTunesConnect!!

Comment: yes, i uploaded screen shots for iPad also.

Comment: so they may test in ipad also.. remove the ipad screen shots and submit for the review.

Comment: i deleted screen shots for iPad and submitted again, but no use again they tested in iPad having iOS version 8.1.1.

Comment: what the reason for rejection

Comment: They used iPad having iOS version 8.1.1 device for testing. In that   video stream not working. but in IPhone (iOS 8.1.1) video and audio both are working properly.